# Attaching product before an order is placed

Tags: magento

I have came across a situation where we need to attach some products based on the cart items. But we don't want customers to see that conditional products. Is there a way, to add certain products, before an order is placed?

I have created an observer for event `sales_order_place_before` and checked the order items and get the conditional products we need to add. But, now how should I attach these products to the order that is going to be created?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding my own answer to help other people with same problem.

in `config.xml`

```
<events>
    <sales_order_save_after>
        <observers>
            <specialitem>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>specialitem/observer</class>
                <method>attachSpecialItem</method>
            </specialitem>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_save_after>
</events>
```

in `Observer.php`

```
public function attachSpecialItem(Varien_Event_Observer $obs) {

    $order = $obs->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $sku = 'SKU OF PRODUCT TO ADD DYNAMICALLY';
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
    $qty = 1;

    $rowTotal = $product->getPrice();
    $order_item = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
            ->setStoreId($order->getStore()->getStoreId())
            ->setQuoteItemId(NULL)
            ->setQuoteParentItemId(NULL)
            ->setProductId($product->getId())
            ->setProductType($product->getTypeId())
            ->setQtyBackordered(NULL)
            ->setTotalQtyOrdered($qty)
            ->setQtyOrdered($qty)
            ->setName($product->getName())
            ->setSku($product->getSku())
            ->setPrice($product->getPrice())
            ->setBasePrice($product->getPrice())
            ->setOriginalPrice($product->getPrice())
            ->setRowTotal($rowTotal)
            ->setBaseRowTotal($rowTotal)
            ->setOrder($order);
    $order_item->save();
}
```